# Anyone know of a good XML editor that can display the data in tables?

Tags: xml, excel, xml-parsing

Excel does this great, but I having hard times re-saving the document in the genuine format. If I save it in an worksheet XML all the data collapses into different cells and I would like not to work that way.

What I need is the ability to add a column that would easily propagate to all data so for example:

```
<theData>
   <client>
      <name> Jade </name>
      <address> 20 Huffborn St. Cleginsville </address>
      <occupation> Graphics designer </occupation>
   </client>
   <client>
      <name> Chad </name>
      <address> 151 Bakersfield St. </address>
      <occupation> Mechanical engineer </occupation>
   </client>
   <client>
      <name> Stephan </name>
      <address> 34 Oakwood St. </address>
      <occupation> Software engineer </occupation>
   </client>
</theData>
```

So, the data should be presented as something like this:

```
1 client:name       client:address                  client:occupation    

2 Jade              20 Huffborn St. Cleginsville    Graphic designer
3 Chad              151 Bakersfield St.             Mechanical engineer
4 Stephan           34 Oakwood St.                  Software engineer
```

I would like (in the table view) simply add another column:

```
1 client:name    client:surname   client:address                  client:occupation    

2 Jade            Levingston      20 Huffborn St. Cleginsville    Graphic designer
3 Chad            Taft            151 Bakersfield St.             Mechanical engineer
4 Stephan         Phillips        34 Oakwood St.                  Software engineer
```

which then will allow me to save the file as:

```
  <theData>
       <client>
          <name> Jade </name>
          <surname> Levingston </surname>
          <address> 20 Huffborn St. Cleginsville </address>
          <occupation> Graphics designer </occupation>
       </client>
       <client>
          <name> Chad </name>
          <surname> Taft </surname>
          <address> 151 Bakersfield St. </address>
          <occupation> Mechanical engineer </occupation>
       </client>
       <client>
          <name> Stephan </name>
          <surname> Phillips </surname>
          <address> 34 Oakwood St. </address>
          <occupation> Software engineer </occupation>
       </client>
    </theData>
```

Again, with the file I am working, I can't save my XML data as excel is complaining about XML maps not being exportable.

Can someone please light up the room here?

Comment: XML data model is not exactly a good fit for tables. Certain flavors of XML should be fine, but not XML in general. I would personally go with exporting to CSV and composing an XML out of it with a Ruby/JS/Python/whatever scripting language.

Answer (score 2):

Your post will be deleted because it doesn't meet the criteria for questions.   But "winhelp xmlpad" may be what you need.

Comment: which criteria may I ask?

Comment: @Ted  It falls under the category "Off Topic"  "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. "

Comment: Thank you Steve... I'm sorry I wasn't aware of it.